# Story of Shlomo and birds

Tags: midrash, king-solomon

Just heard today that apparently there’s some midrash where Shlomo sees two birds perched on top of his castle and he overheard one bird saying to the other “with the stomp of my foot I can crumble this castle.” Shlomo, shocked and scared, calls over the bird and says “can you really destroy this castle with just one kick?” The bird replies “nah, that other bird was my wife and I was just trying to show off.”

Is this a real midrash or is it just a joke?

Comment: *or is it for the birds